# Something's wrong with the C++ versions

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-versions

I noticed some of the topics in C++ didn't show their versions right, and found that there were two "versions" for every actual version of the language, one with caps and one without. Looking at the indroduction topic, there was only one for each. How did this happen? Is it related to how the versions section uses inline tags?

Comment: Could you provide a link to an exact spot where the issue is occurring?

Comment: @animuson Try editing a topic title in [some random topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/7660/iostream-library/25277/parsing-files#t=201611011417101517458).